# select2 - How to change the value to the first option of the list with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a form with a [`select2`](https://select2.github.io/) dropdown.

The dropdown is in a "modal" window and I want to be able to reset my form when the modal is closed.

Behaviour wanted: When the modal is opened, I want the default value to be the first option in my select.

```
<select id="mylist">
    <option value="4">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="1">C</option>
    <option value="3">D</option>
</select>
```

In this case, the selected value would be `A` (value = 4).

Note that these values are populated dynamically and it cannot be hardcoded.

My reset function would be:

```
function reset() {
    $('#mylist').val( /* Code I'm looking for goes here */ );
}
```

Comment: `$('#mylist')[0].selectedIndex = 0;` will do the trick

Comment: Works with normal `<select>`. Not working with `select2`.

Comment: select2 has its own method for selecting an option by value. See the "Programmatic access" section of their Examples in their docs. eg.  $("#mylist").select2("val", "A");

Comment: @mmccaff The method you are refering is deprecated.  Also, I did not want to select A or value = 4.  I wanted to select the **first** value in the list.  This is different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just after I posted my question I found something that was working with `select2('val', ..)` but it is [deprecated in 4.0](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html) and will be removed in 4.1.

The missing part on my end was triggering the `change` event... as I saw in the deprecated documentation. I added it and the event fired the value update!

Here is what finally worked:

```
$('#mylist').val($('#mylist option:first-child').val()).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the "show.bs.modal" event and the .prop() method in jQuery we can do this easily.

```
$("#my-modal").on("show.bs.modal", function() {

    $(this).find("select option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);

});
```

This would fire every time the modal is opened and because we're using "show.bs.modal" instead of "shown.bs.modal" you shouldn't even see the selection being changed.

Answer (score 0):

**For all select2 in form:**

```
$('#formId select').each( function( key, value ) {
  $(this).val($(this).find('option:first-child').val()).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Select first option of your select(s) - works not only for select2

```
$('#myForm').find('select').find('option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');
```

**Step 2:** Trigger select2 change

```
$('#myForm select').trigger('change.select2');
```

In your specific case:

```
$('#mylist').find('option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');
$('#mylist select').trigger('change.select2');
```